# Javasctipt Uncaught custom exception.Even though it should catch the general error class

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, error-handling, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have created a custom exception class that extends from error. I am using es6 classes.

`class Myexception extends Error{}`

I have a try catch in my code that should catch all errors yet from the browser  I receive the Uncaught exception: Myexception.I tried a lot to find an answer for this but nobody seems to mention it. Why even though the catch block should catch error and myexception extends error gives me this uncaught.
Ps: If I check inside my catch block about that specific exception with instanceof the error goes away. Also, this happens only on chrome, not on firefox.

```
    try {
          throw new Myexception('haha');
            } catch (error) {
                if (error instanceof Myexception) {
                   the item may not be present in the DOM
                }else{
                    throw error;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Probably [you should read this Forum](https://gist.github.com/justmoon/15511f92e5216fa2624b) which has few working solutions to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the link as I explain above I have solved my problem by checking inside the code if its the instance of Myexception the problem is that specifically in chrome we have this weird behaviour where the error is uncaught if its custom in the catch.I am trying to understand why?

Comment: Sure, Please do post here (as answer) if you find the answer to the problem. It may help someone in future.